# twisted check client SSL trustRoot value

Tags: ssl, openssl, twisted

I'm working on a twisted server where there should be a two way SSL handshake. I'm very new to working with these tools so I'm not sure how to set this option. This is my reactor:

```
def main(reactor):

   with open('/opt/ssl/cert.pem') as f:
       certdata = f.read()

   with open('/opt/ssl/issuer.pem') as f:
       issuer_certdata = f.read()

   log.info("SSL Certificate Loaded.")

   certificate = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certdata)
   issuer_certificate = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(issuer_certdata)

   options = ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=certificate.privateKey.original,
                                 certificate=certificate.original,
                                 raiseMinimumTo=ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2,
                                 trustRoot=ssl.trustRootFromCertificates([issuer_certificate]))

   factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(MPG)
   reactor.listenSSL(6060, factory, options)

return defer.Deferred()
```

From reading https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.2.0/api/twisted.internet.ssl.CertificateOptions.html, I found I need to be using the trustRoot argument, and pass it an object that holds the CA. Now, in my case, the server and the clients all have the same CA, so I pass that certificate, such that the CA from that certificate is trusted.

Yet, this doesn't work somehow, and our wireshark tests fail with an error message saying with `unknown CA` during client certificate valdiation. I don't know if that is because I configured the twisted server wrong, or because the CA info simply doesn't match.

Edit: Since Jean-Paul's original comment, I've tried using the intermediary, the CA and both of them combined as the trustRoot argument, using trustRootFromCertificates. All of them result in an unknown CA error.

PS. I'm on a Centos7, and I've updated `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` to include the CA certificate. and ran `update-ca-trust`

PS2. Testing my server with the command below, I found that it can't validate my own chain when I delete trustRoot from my code above. `openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:6060 -tls1_2 -state -cert cert.pem -key cert.pem`

That is, without the trustRoot argument, this is the certificate chain from openssl:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = TR, O = MYCERT
   i:C = TR, CN = MYCERT's issuer
---
```

While, with the trustRoot argument I'm getting:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = TR, O = MYCE
   i:C = TR, CN = MYCERT's issuer
 1 s:C = TR, CN = MYCERT's issuer
   i:C = TR, L = ROOT CA
---
```

I don't know why trustRoot causes this change. I'm probably misunderstanding the whole thing, and am very lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless /opt/ssl/cert.pem is *self-signed* this is the wrong trust root.  Pass the cert that signed the server cert, instead.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work. I've added my own CA certificate such that it appears in /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt. I've also tried using the root certificate, the intermediary certificate and both of them together as inputs to platformTrust but none of them works.

Comment: Try editing your question into a self-contained, complete, minimal example

Comment: I don't quite know how to provide you with a minimal example here. I don't know much about configuring SSL with twisted and I am LOST on how to use this. I've provided my main reactor above, which should be enough as a minimal example, but that shouldn't matter since to you won't be able to replicate the problem without the certificates. I'm looking for guidance. Please help me out instead of asking me to guess what you want from me.

Comment: See http://sscce.org/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can add the commands you used to generate your certificates to the question, too.  It is likely that the core of the problem has to do with the certificates themselves so there's probably no answer without knowing exactly how they are constructed and how they related to each other.